# How to get values include "time" onclick to textarea when checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to get some values/text from input `checkbox` include time (`new Date()` JS) when checked every value to `textarea`. My problem is time result always same for all value checked?

Please give me solution for this script.
http://jsfiddle.net/zNfju/83/

```js
$(function() {
    $('.cb').on('click', function() {
        var values = [];
        var d = new Date();
        var now = "(" + d.getFullYear() + "-" + d.getMonth() + "-" + d.getDay() + "-" + d.getHours() + "-" + d.getMinutes() + "-" + d.getSeconds() + ")";
        
        $('input:checked').map(function() {
            values.push($(this).parent().text()+"-"+now);
        });
        $("#CBX").val(values.join(', '));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Chechkbox1</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Chechkbox2</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Chechkbox3</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Chechkbox4</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Chechkbox5</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Chechkbox6</label><br />
<textarea id="CBX" rows="10" style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: What is the problem? As written, you calculate the current time, then set all the checked checkboxes values to this time. This isn't the logic you want?

Comment: The problem is time result always same when checked every checkbox, it must different because time is current time from JS, Ex: Chechkbox1-(2015-7-1-16-8-20), Chechkbox2-(2015-7-1-16-8-30),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calculating the current date every time an option is clicked, and use it for all checked inputs. If you don't want this, save the time/date somewhere when it is clicked, such as in a data-attribute. Then use the data-attribute instead for rendering.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.cb').on('click', function() {
        var values = [];
        var d = new Date();
        var now = "(" + d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getDate() + "-" + d.getHours() + "-" + d.getMinutes() + "-" + d.getSeconds() + ")";
        $(this).data( "date", now );
        
        $('input:checked').map(function() {
            values.push($(this).parent().text()+"-"+$(this).data( "date" ));
        });
        $("#CBX").val(values.join(', '));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Checkbox1</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Checkbox2</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Checkbox3</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Checkbox4</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Checkbox5</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Checkbox6</label><br />
<textarea id="CBX" rows="10" style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

---

If you have already got checked checkboxes upon loading the page, you can render each of the checked tags with their own "data-date" attribute. It would look something like this. This assumes that you have this information on the server.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.cb').on('click', function() {
        var values = [];
        var d = new Date();
        var now = "(" + d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getDate() + "-" + d.getHours() + "-" + d.getMinutes() + "-" + d.getSeconds() + ")";
        $(this).data( "date", now );
        
        $('input:checked').map(function() {
            values.push($(this).parent().text()+"-"+$(this).data( "date" ));
        });
        $("#CBX").val(values.join(', '));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb" checked data-date="(2015-8-25-10-8-14)" />Checkbox1</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Checkbox2</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb" checked data-date="(2015-8-25-10-8-21)" />Checkbox3</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Checkbox4</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Checkbox5</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Checkbox6</label><br />
<textarea id="CBX" rows="10" style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

If you don't have this data on the server, you can dynamically add the current date to all checkboxes that were already checked.

```js
var d = new Date();
var now = "(" + d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getDate() + "-" + d.getHours() + "-" + d.getMinutes() + "-" + d.getSeconds() + ")";

$(function() {
    $('.cb').on('click', function() {
        var values = [];
        var d = new Date();
        var now = "(" + d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getDate() + "-" + d.getHours() + "-" + d.getMinutes() + "-" + d.getSeconds() + ")";
        $(this).data( "date", now );
        
        $('input:checked').map(function() {
            values.push($(this).parent().text()+"-"+$(this).data( "date" ));
        });
        $("#CBX").val(values.join(', '));
    }).filter( ":checked" ).data( "date", now );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb" checked/>Checkbox1</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Checkbox2</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb" checked/>Checkbox3</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Checkbox4</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Checkbox5</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="cb"/>Checkbox6</label><br />
<textarea id="CBX" rows="10" style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thx Sumurai8 your script is good but i have new problem :D,  if textarea before have a value from checked checkbox and a checked again why time(now) before value change to "undefined". Ex: Checkbox1-undefined, Checkbox2-(2015-7-1-16-35-46)  *I Implements this script on CRUD PHP and this problem when editing. thx

Comment: If a checkbox is already checked when the page is loaded, make sure you render it with the `data-date="..."` already in the input tag.

Comment: I've edited the answer to change `d.getDay()` to `d.getDate()`, because `getDay()` gets the day of the week. `d.getMonth()` gets a value between 0 and 11, which is one less than what we intuitively would expect, so I changed it to `(d.getMonth() + 1)`.

Comment: this is case checkbox is already checked and value now(time) always change to undefined, http://jsfiddle.net/riza24/658fqwq8/, please give me solutions for it

Comment: I've updated the answer with how to handle checkboxes that were already checked

Answer (score 1):

Because you are pushing new values each time from all the checked `checkbox`. So better to check whether the `checkbox` is `checked` or `unchecked` and based on that `push` and `pop` the values from array.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zNfju/87/)**

```
$(function() {
    var values = [];
    $('.cb').on('click', function() {
        var d = new Date();
        var now = "(" + d.getFullYear() + "-" + d.getMonth() + "-" + d.getDay() + "-" + d.getHours() + "-" + d.getMinutes() + "-" + d.getSeconds() + ")";
        if($(this).is(":checked"))//If is checked push the value
        {    
            values.push($(this).parent().text()+"-"+now);
        }
        else
        {
            values.pop($(this).parent().text()+"-"+now);//else pop it out
        }
        $("#CBX").val(values.join(', ')); //then the same routine
    });
});
```

Comment: Thx Guruprasad Rao your script always delete value on textarea, if textarea before have a value from checked checkbox and a checked again *I Implements this script on CRUD PHP and this problem when editing. thx

Comment: So you are saying during **uncheck** you need to keep the `value` in array? and delete it only from `textarea`?

Comment: No, sorry. Ex: Checkbox 1 is checked, i want when editing process(CRUD) when i checked Checkbox 2 and Checkbox 1 still checked and available on textarea not deleted, not only value Checkbox 2 on textarea

Comment: Its really confusing.. Your example, doesn't seem to clarify properly!

Comment: I have upload to http://jsfiddle.net/riza24/zNfju/90/, the problem is if checkbox 1 checked and i checked again checkbox 4, checkbox 1 is lost/deleted, thx Guruprasad, please help me

Comment: @user2483073.. Something like this? **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zNfju/91/)**

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting result with:

```
$("#CBX").val(values.join(', '));
```

Try something like this:

```
$("#CBX").val($("#CBX").val() + values.join(', '));
```